# MIPS How to read directly from text segment.(Mars Simulator)

Tags: mips, runtimeexception

Im trying to count the add and lw instructions count in the program, so i want to first locate the addresses of the instructions. I used labels to locate them as start and end, between start and end i want to count the add and lw instructions. However while im trying to load the value at the address to see the instructions register content i get error

```
Runtime exception at 0x00400048: Cannot read directly from text segment!0x00400020
```

How can i load the register content at $a0 address, my instruction looks like this.

```
main:
li $t0,1
li $t1,4
li $t2,6
li $t5,0

start:add $t0,$t1,$t2
add $t0,$t5,$t2
add $t3,$t2,$t1
lw $t5,num
lw $t2,test
add $t4,$zero,$t1
end:lw $t4,test2
la $a0,start
la $a1,end
lw $s0,0($a0)
```

Comment: You haven't specified what your target environment is. If you're using the MARS simulator, there a `Self modifying code` option that you can enable in the settings menu. I don't know if QtSpim or other simulators have similar options.

Comment: @Michael, thanks it is solved if you share your comment as solution i'll correct it.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunate but that's how it works.  Ideally, there would be an option to allow reading from text but not writing to text.  Even an exception handler running privileged cannot read the user text without this option, and of course, a sufficiently rich exception handler needs to be able read the instruction that caused the exception, but basically never needs to write to the user text.